# set multiple Strings for the same index

Tags: list, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin language, and I want to make a login/register app simple for training. I have a problem when I want to store the username and password inside a list but both in the same index for the same account. For example:

```
var login = mutableListOf<String?>({"username1","password1"} , {"username2","password2"})
```

I tried searching for a way to do this but i did not found an answer. Sorry if it is the wrong section as it's my first time on this forum, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example looks more like a map, so consider using a map like

`mapOf("username1" to "password1" , "username2" to "password2")`.

But if you definitely need list of lists then maybe

`listOf(listOf("username1", "password1"), listOf("username2", "password2"))`

is what you are looking for.

There is also a nice facility in Kt - Pair

`listOf(Pair("username1", "password1"), Pair("username2", "password2"))`